# Is there a way to know WHEN a connection has been established?

Tags: tcpip, lsof

I'm working with mobile IPv6 and was dealing with lots of zombie connections. I set `keepAlive` to true and want to test whether old connections are being discarded.

I'm using `lsof` to list the process connections, but I can't tell how old the connection is.

Is there a way to verify this?

Answer (score 0):

netstat -nlp

- -n for not resolving the ips
- -l for listening sockets. Skip this if you want to list outgoing connections
- -p to show executable name (last column) and process id

edit:

ow. WHEN. That kind of information is not kept... Well at least for TCP/IP. If it's a unix socket you can try with socket file times (created, modified ...)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't show the connection date.

Comment: sorry. didn't read correctly. what you want is not possible